# AS3 - Draggable squares generate from an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Good Morning,
I have a grid (`bankgrid`) generated by a `var bankArray:Array` who takes Array's value to show by a gotoAndStop(that number (`f`)) a colorful grid.
 All squares are children from the same MovieClip(`TBank`) generates one after one with horizontal(`i`) and vertical (`j`) position in the Array.
I'm trying to make there squares draggable... in vain :

```
var bankgrille:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var bankList:Vector.<TBank> = new Vector.<TBank>();

var bankArray:Array = [
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0],
                     [0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0],
                     [0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0],
                     [0,2,1,1,2,1,1,0]
                     ];
var bankstock:Array = [
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                     ];

function colorBank():void {
    for (var i:int=0; i<8; i++){                                    // boucle sur les 20 colonnes
        for (var j:int=0; j<8; j++){                                // boucle sur les 15 lignes de chaque colonne
            var f:int = bankArray[j][i]                             // valeur de la case

            if(f > 0)
            {                                                       // si la valeur de la case est supérieure à 0
                var tBank:TBank = new TBank()
                bankList.push(tBank);
                // création du modèle
                tBank.x = 320+i*20;                                     // position sur X
                tBank.y = 100+j*20;                                     // position sur Y
                tBank.gotoAndStop(f);
                bankgrille.addChild(tBank); 

            }

            else 
            {
                bankstock[j][i] = []                                
            }

        }
    }
}
colorBank();
addChild(bankgrille);
```

*My future project (to maybe make my question more senseful) :
'After that, I'd like to permit to drag there squares and drop them on another Array to change second one colours'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And Voilà ! Thank you again Sim !

```
var bankgrille:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var bankList:Vector.<TBank> = new Vector.<TBank>();

var bankArray:Array = [
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0],
                     [0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0],
                     [0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0],
                     [0,2,1,1,2,1,1,0]
                     ];
var bankstock:Array = [
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                     ];

function colorBank():void {
    for (var i:int=0; i<8; i++){                                    // boucle sur les 20 colonnes
        for (var j:int=0; j<8; j++){                                // boucle sur les 15 lignes de chaque colonne
            var f:int = bankArray[j][i]                             // valeur de la case

            if(f > 0)
            {                                                       // si la valeur de la case est supérieure à 0
                var tBank:TBank = new TBank()
                bankList.push(tBank);
                // création du modèle
                tBank.x = 320+i*20;                                     // position sur X
                tBank.y = 100+j*20;                                     // position sur Y
                tBank.gotoAndStop(f);
                bankgrille.addChild(tBank); 

            }

            else 
            {
                bankstock[j][i] = []                                
            }

        }
    }
}
colorBank();
addChild(bankgrille);

draggable();
function draggable()
{
    for each(var t:TBank in bankList)
    {
t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clik);
t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, lache);
var posX=t.x;
  if (t.x != posX)
  {
      t.x = posX;
  }
function clik(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function lache(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  e.currentTarget.stopDrag();  
}
}
}
```

Comment: No problem =) Be sure to look at the two parameters you can include in `startDrag()`: the first is a Boolean to centre the dragged object and the second is a rectangle object if you want to constrain the drag (so you can't drag it outside of a certain area for example).

Answer (score 1):

`startDrag()` is a good place to start when it comes to dragging movie clips.

You can assign a `MouseEvent` listener to the entire grid and drag a specific element using `event.currentTarget`:

```
bankgrille.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
bankgrille.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Actually that code permites to move the entire grid, but it shall help me ! I'll post evolution, questions (and the solution if I get it !)